# authentication for GCP STT Quickstart problem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-authentication

I am following the GCP Speech-to-Text Quickstart.  As best as I can tell, I have followed all setup criteria.

- Enabled STT for my project.
- Generated Service API keys and downloaded the JSON file.
- Installed SDK and initialized.
- In Windows CMD shell, I set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the downloaded JSON file.
- In Windows CMD shell, I executed `gcloud auth activate-service-account <my service email generated by GCP>  --key-file= "mypath/JSON key file"`.
- I executed `gcloud auth list` and I see my project account identifier.

I executed the example curl command:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize -d @sync-request.json
```

And get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

No where in the Quickstart steps does it mention OAuth

As a test, I executed:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

And got this:

```
(gcloud.auth.application-default.print-access-token) File "mypath/JSON key file" was not found.
```

Even though the file exists in the folder I specify.

Trying something else, I tried executing the Java example in the SDK.  It creates a very simple `SpeechClient` with no credentials, which seems suspect.  I made the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable available to the example.  I think the example uses gRCP, but not sure.

The example hangs at:

```
RecognizeResponse response = speech.recognize(config, audio);
```

Looking online, I found the likely suspect is bad authentication, which is the same as trying the CMD line example.

Any and all guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Hey, Ricco. Can you provide more info on the Windows  version you are using? Also, where you are storing this JSON?

I suspect the environment variable might not be setup correctly. You can verify the pat of the variable using `echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%`

I recommend using the full path you get when running `cd` alone. Also, please refer to this documentation for multiple ways to verify authentication too https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable

Comment: Ah, sorry, Ricco was the editor.

Just to be clear, run `cd` by itself in the directory where the JSON is, that will be the full path. Also, try using other APIs, since it's highly likely this issue is not only for TTS

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the curl command from the same directory where your JSON key file is located?

Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol#make_an_audio_transcription_request) states the following:

> Note that to pass a filename to curl you use the -d option (for
> "data") and precede the filename with an @ sign. This file should be
> in the same directory in which you execute the curl command.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer to the CLI issue.  A dumb mistake on my part.  When I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS I wrapped the pathname in double quotes.  Sigh.  I reset the env variable without the double quotes.
I could successfully run gcloud auth application-default print-access-token and it printed out the token.
I tried the curl command again with $(gcloud auth....) and got same error.  Next, I tried the curl command replacing the $(gcloud auth....) with the token returned above and it worked!

Next, I need to resolve the Java example and I am good.

Answer (score 0):

No need to be suspicious:

> If you don't specify credentials when constructing the client, the client library will look for credentials via the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

In your java code try to print `System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")`, to verify it's set . Probably it's not, depending on how you are setting it in your IDE, or terminal.